# Spark 2.3 Dataframe partition-want to partition data on key in n number of partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I need help in spark(scala) dataframe partitioning. I need to partition by a key column into n number of partition with all rows related to same key should be in same partition (i.e. key should not be distributed across partition)

Note: My key may have millions in count

Ex:
Suppose I have below dataframe

[image]

and so on

As you can see many values shares same key.
I want to partition this dataset into "n" number of partitions where same key should be in same partition and keys should not be distributed across partitions.
Multiple keys cab be in same partition
and keys are not sortable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use partitionBy(colName) to save dataFrame

Answer (score 0):

According to the book `Spark - The Definitive Guide` Spark has two built-in Partitioners, a `HashPartitioner`for discrete values and a `RangePartitioner`. Both work for discrete values and continuous values.

**Example HashPartitioner:**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val rdd = df.rdd // convert DataFrame to low-level RDD
val keyedRDD = rdd.keyBy(...) // define your custom key
keyedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))
```

**Example Partitioner:**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

class DomainParitioner extends Partitioner {
  def numPartitions = n
  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    // your custome partition logic
  }
}

keyedRDD.partitionBy(new DomainPartitioner).map(_._1).glom().map(_.toSet.toSeq.length)
```

In the book it is also mentioned that you should watch out for `key skew` which means that some keys may have many, many more values than other keys. You want to break these keys as much as possible to improve parallelism and prevent `OutOfMemoryErrors` during the course of execution.

Comment: Thanks Mike,I guess hashpartitioner would work but my dataframe is very large and complex, is there any way I can achive this on dataframe directory because converting in rdd and then back to dataframe is time and resource consuming.

Comment: Unfortunately, the custom partitioners are not available in the Structured API.

Comment: I was actually reading a blog (https://acadgild.com/blog/partitioning-in-spark), here they gave an example with custom partition but have to look for implementation for my problem

Comment: This blog looks really good and seems to be very helpful. Having a short look at it, it seems that this is all based as well on RDDs and reflects the examples in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition DataFrames while writing them to file based Output. Something like:

```
df.write.partitionBy("colName").format("parquet").save(path-to-file)
```

This will create the directory structure as in your

```
path
└── to
    └── file
         ├── colName=value1
                       └── data.parquet
         ├── colName=value2
                       └── data.parquet
```

When you load the data and filters, predicates will be pushed down to the source file and you can get performance benefits of partitioning

Is this not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def repartition(partitionExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*): org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

```
val df = Seq(("aa","vv"),("aa","v1v1"),("a1","v2")).toDF("Key","Value")
 val partionedDf = df.repartition(col("Key"))
```